# When did people begin getting old?

Tags: age

I barely remember the details, but I once heard that people before certain time did't get old (physically). That even at 100 years old people looked like young adults. Is this in the Torah? When and why did it happen?

Comment: Please, feel free to edit.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of a question that is, technically, a little more specific from yours, but also contains the answer to your question.  If you disagree that it's a duplicate we can undo that, though it'd be good to edit in something that clarifies the difference between what you're asking and that one.  Thanks for bringing your question here.

Comment: Gabe12, I've undeleted this so I could respond to you.  Duplicates aren't bad; they provide extra paths to the answer.  If you had found the question on your own you wouldn't have needed to ask; next time there'll be two questions for people to come across while searching for this answer.  If you really want to delete this go ahead, but I hope you won't.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks, I won't delete this question. ;)